# Calculate duration using timestamps (string)

Tags: javascript, react-native, datetime, timestamp

Newcomer here to the coding world.

I've written this chunk of code to calculate the time difference (duration) between two timestamps. I'm pretty happy with it. But I want to know if there is any way I can improve on what I wrote and get the same outcome.

Here's an example,

```
  const startTime = 2202-05-12 + "T" + 10:00:00 + "Z"
  const endTime = 2202-05-12 + "T" + 11:45:00 + "Z"

  const format_startTime = new Date(startTime);
  const format_endTime = new Date(endTime)

  const hours_startTime = format_startTime.getHours()
  const hours_endTime = format_endTime.getHours()

  const min_startTime = format_startTime.getMinutes()
  const min_endTime = format_endTime.getMinutes()

  const hours_Duration = hours_endTime - hours_startTime
  const min_Duration = min_endTime - min_startTime

  const min_Decimal = min_Duration * (1/60)

  const duration = hours_Duration + (min_Decimal === 0 ? '' : min_Decimal) + " hours";
```

Result - 1.75 hours

Edit 1 - to clarify, the requirement for this exercise is to use date and time in string format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subtract one timestamp directly from the other to get the difference in milliseconds.  Your version will also only be accurate if both timestamps are on the same day.

```js
  const startTime = "2202-05-12T10:00:00Z"
  const endTime = "2202-05-12T11:45:00Z"

  const format_startTime = new Date(startTime);
  const format_endTime = new Date(endTime);

  const differenceInMillis = format_endTime - format_startTime;
  const differenceInHours = differenceInMillis / 1000 / 60 / 60; // 1.75
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Thanks, Abe!

Comment: no problem!  glad it worked for you

Comment: nice one, will edit the answer